# Django forms - filter field by user.id

Tags: python, django

I have the following situation with Django that i cannot resolve. How to filter/sort field 'training' to represent only the trainings that are owned by the user that is logged in. Thank you in advance!

```
class Exercise(mоdels.Model):
    MAX_LENGTH = 25
    name = mоdels.CharField(
        mаx_length=MAX_LENGTH
    )
    weight = mоdels.IntegerField()
    series = mоdels.IntegerField()
    reps = mоdels.IntegerField()
    training = models.FоreignKey('Workout', оn_delete=mоdels.CASCADE)


class CreateExerciseFоrm(forms.ModelFоrm):
    class Meta:
        model = SingleExercisе
        fields = ('name', 'weight', 'series', 'reps', 'training', )
```

Comment: Could you please post "Workout" model

Comment: Hello, please find the attached pastebin link, because it is too long to post it here.
https://pastebin.com/ztEpKaCx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `__init__` method of your form so that you can pass an additional argument and modify the queryset of your field based on that argument. To accept a `user` keyword argument:

```
class CreateExerciseFоrm(forms.ModelFоrm):
    class Meta:
        model = SingleExercisе
        fields = ('name', 'weight', 'series', 'reps', 'training')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user:
            self.fields['training'].queryset = Workout.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Then in your view you pass the logged in user to your form

```
    form = CreateExerciseFоrm(user=request.user)
```

And when you pass POST data

```
    form = CreateExerciseFоrm(request.POST, user=request.user)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! Now i can continue my journey in my Django education!

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference when calling the form from the get and post methods.